# Can Django admin show the image after the model name?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a problem.

Can I add image after the Model name in the django admin?

[The postion I want to add the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3sz2.png)

I want to see the books image when I login admin page

I have no idea about it

maybe I can use verbose_name with inject html tag?

Can django do it? Or I should use others way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, You could customize [**`ModelAdmin.list_display`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) in Django `admin list view`, for example:

Suppose you have a model `MyModel` with an image field named `image`

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'image_tag')

    def image_tag(self, obj):
        return format_html("<img src="{}" width=200 height=80/>'.format(obj.image.url))
    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

Comment: Thx for your answer
I finished it by overwriting  the admin/index.html and admin/app_index.html.